# Rename Shape File which saves as TableName using Geotools - JAVA

Tags: java, geotools

I am trying to save a shapefile which works fine as followed by this question link here:

[Add new column attribute to the shapefile and save it to database using Geotools Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554587/add-new-column-attribute-to-the-shapefile-and-save-it-to-database-using-geotools)

The problem I face is with the **fileName** of the shapefile, which **contains a blank space** and it turns out to save as `%20` equivalent to space n db.

**For eg:** `New File abc.shp ==>  New%20File%20abc` (TableName)

I know we could rename the filePath, but in my case i want to rename the file chosen, as opposed to renaming a file on the filesystem.

**EDIT**

Using Geotools I am using the following code to store the tableName:

```
  File FilePath = new File("/users/New File abc.shp");
 FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File(FilePath.toString()));
    SimpleFeatureType schema = ds.getSchema();
    // create new schema
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName(schema.getName());
    builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
    builder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());

    // build new schema
    SimpleFeatureType nSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();
    System.out.println("Shapefile table info : " + nSchema);
```

Is there any way I could do it using Java  or is there any solution using Geotools. The DB I am using is PostGIS.

Comment: This is probably an artifact of the URL to file conversion process, how exactly are you creating your datastore

Comment: @IanTurton I have updated my question. I thought i need to change the table name in the nSchema, but I see the schema link. So just can't get it right

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. We need to see how you are creating the Shapefile datastore, though you will still need to replace the spaces with _ to make a table name work

Comment: @IanTurton i have updated with the full code. Including the shapefile ds.

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks for ur guidance, I changed my code at this line

 builder.setName(schema.getName().toString().replaceAll("%20", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_"));

Comment: and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems pretty simple, because I was only focusing on changing the filePath. But a simple solution as per Ian's comment gave me the idea. I just had to rename the schema name after loading the file.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
 File FilePath = new File("/users/New File abc.shp");
 FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File(FilePath.toString()));
    SimpleFeatureType schema = ds.getSchema();
    // create new schema
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    builder.setName(schema.getName().toString().replaceAll("%20", "_").replaceAll(" ", "_"));
    builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
    builder.addAll(schema.getAttributeDescriptors());

    // build new schema
    SimpleFeatureType nSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();
    System.out.println("Shapefile table info : " + nSchema);
```

Just a note, we could also change the fileName using renameTo in java, but that causes to change the other file in shapefile which is not a good idea if ur scaling an application like this.